# MySQL UPDATE with JOIN, SELECT and GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, asterisk

PRETEXT:

I'm currently trying to create detailed and correct call statistics for our customers. Previously, Asterisk stored call details in one row per call. One row is not enough to store all the possible things that can happen to a call, and the data would often be misleading or wrong. They now have a new table format that stores one row per event in the call. This table will easily contain millions of records for our larger customers.

We tried selecting directly from this table on a test server with only 200k records, but the more advanced queries ended up taking forever. We decided to create a summary table (so we're back to one row per call, but now with more details available). There are many things I'd like to do with this data, but if I can solve this "simple" problem, I'm sure I'll solve all the others as well.

PROBLEM:

The field linkedid is the same for all rows in one call. The field eventtype can have zero, one or multiple occurances of the same event for one linkedid.

I fill the summary table with some data:

```
INSERT INTO astcel_summary
(linkedid, starttime, endtime, callfrom, callto, direction)
SELECT 
linkedid, MIN(eventtime), MAX(eventtime), cid_num, exten, IF ((context = 'from-extension'), 1, 0)
FROM astcel
GROUP BY linkedid;
```

The BRIDGE_START event is especially important as it indicates that a person answered the call. The call can be unanswered, answered or even answered multiple times (transfer, conference). I want to UPDATE my summary table with **several** fields from the **first** (if any) BRIDGE_START event for each call.

I've been able to update one field at a time like this:

```
UPDATE astcel_summary, astcel
SET astcel_summary.answertime = 
(
SELECT eventtime
FROM astcel
WHERE astcel.linkedid = astcel_summary.linkedid
AND astcel.eventtype = 'BRIDGE_START'
GROUP BY astcel.linkedid
)
WHERE astcel.linkedid = astcel_summary.linkedid
AND astcel.eventtype = 'BRIDGE_START';
```

I've tried many variations with different joins and subqueries to update multiple fields, but can't make it work. If this operation could also be merged with the original insert somehow, that would be amazing.

Even better would be a way to select, without using summary tables and without it taking too long time, for instance: The average time callers waited before being answered (plus several other similar pieces of data) during business hours last month grouped by the numbers called.

Comment: Why can't you make it work?  What is the MySQL error code?

Comment: Well, I did almost make it work. My best effort actually updates several columns, but it updates them even if the call is unanswered. For some reason this update changes the field answertime (timestamp) from "0000-00-00 00:00:00" to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. `UPDATE astcel_summary s LEFT JOIN (SELECT linkedid, eventtime, peer FROM astcel WHERE eventtype = 'BRIDGE_START' GROUP BY linkedid) AS c USING(linkedid) SET s.answertime = c.eventtime, s.peer = c.peer;`

Comment: Fixed that problem now with `SET s.answertime = IFNULL(c.eventtime,'0000-00-00 00:00:00')`. It would probably be better to have NULL checking in a WHERE clause like `WHERE c.peer IS NOT NULL`, but I can't make that work for some reason. It gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Why not give us some representative (plausible if not real) data to play with? Oh, this thread is old!